# javascript / jquery get value of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript, the way to declare a var is: var msg = 'hello', and it is simply to call msg will get the value of 'hello'
if I am now have a number of var, e.g. msg_1, msg_2 ... msg_n would there be a way to get the value by calling something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
 var var_name = 'msg_' + i;
 alert (var_name)?
}
```

Comment: `eval()`. Haters gonna hate

Comment: Use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead

Comment: If it's global `alert(window[var_name])`.

Comment: @Johan: `eval`ers gonna `eval`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat No, they're gonna `evaluate` ;)

Answer (score 3):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R8sp5/1)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var var_name = 'msg_' + i;
    window[var_name] = i;
    console.log(window[var_name]);
}
```

Comment: You mean `window[var_name]` :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should put the values inside an array.

```
var messages = ["first", "second", "third"];

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    alert (messages[i])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use to use `array` instead of what you are doing.

```
var myVarialbes= [];
for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    myVarialbes[i] = "some stuff" + i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you got a simple method:

```
var var_name=''; //declare variable only once
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) //You should change 5 to n
{
 var_name = 'msg_' + i;
 alert (var_name.split('_')[1]);
}
```

Comment: if you don't understand how it works don't click -1

Answer (score 0):

```
function do_test(){
    var v1 = "variable 1";
    var v2 = "variable 2";
    var v3 = "variable 3";
    for (i=1;i<4;i++){
        var o = eval("v"+i); // you actually need this
        alert (o);
    }
}
```

But why don't you use arrays?